# Calculation of Market portfolio from efficient frontier

Tags: portfolio-management, finance, portfolio-optimization, asset-allocation

I have a specific Portfolio frontier. Can someone provides me with details about how can I calculate the market portfolio from the efficient frontier? I know that I have to draw the tangent line from the risk free asset, but how? is there any specific formula to calculate the risk free asset? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: To draw the tangent line, you need to know what the risk-free rate $R_f$ is. The tangent line goes through point $(0,R_f)$.

Comment: @stans thank you for your answer. And how can I know the value for $R_f$ ?

Comment: Somebody should give it to you. The professor if this is an assignment. Bloomberg / Quandl if this is a personal project.

Comment: No It is a research project. I don't have $R_f$, but I think I have to calculate the sharp ratio curve and then find the market portfolio.

Comment: As I said, go to data bases. You need $R_f$, which in your case is the LIBOR rate. Publicly known... Either way, real-life trading based on mean-variance principles is not a very successful thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @stans already said in the comments to your question, the existence of the market portfolio hinges on the existence of a risk free rate $r_f$, where *risk free*, in this context, means that its value can be perfectly contracted for the relevant return horizon, e.g. you will with probability one get that rate for 1 month or 1 year. In theory, we must also be able to lend out and/or borrow at that same risk free rate.

For sake of argument, let us assume that you have queried the [LIBOR rates](https://www.global-rates.com/en/interest-rates/libor/american-dollar/usd-libor-interest-rate-6-months.aspx) or any other interbank rates panel for the relevant risk free rates.*

---

**What does the tangency condition imply?**

Draw a line from the $0,r_f$ point in your diagram such that it is tangent to your efficient frontier. Without knowning the market point ab initio, let us just call that point $M$, and let us denote its expected return and its volatility as $\mu_m$ and $\sigma_M$.

Given this (yet unknown) point, the formula for the capital market line $L$ is:

$$
\mu_L=r_f+\frac{\mu_M-r_f}{\sigma_M}\sigma
$$

i.e. if $\sigma = \sigma_M$, the line is at the market point and has an expected return of $\mu_L=\mu_M$. Furthermore, given any investment weight vector $\mathbb{w}$, the assets' expected return vector $\mathbb{\mu}$ and the assets' covariance matrix $\mathbb{\Sigma}$, our portfolio's expected return is:

$$
\mu_p(\mathbb{w})=r_f + \left(\mathbb{\mu}-\mathbb{1}r_f\right)^T\mathbb{w} \qquad 
$$
NB: With a risk free rate in the mix, we *could* add it to our portfolio (and in the efficient frontier its weight is simply fixed at zero,though).

... and our portfolio's volatility is:
$$
\sigma_p(\mathbb{w})=\left(\mathbb{w}^T\mathbb{\Sigma}\mathbb{w}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}
$$

At the tangency point (*market point*) the slope of the capital market line $L$ and the slope of the efficient frontier (at portfolio $p$) are equal, i.e.

$$
\left.\frac{\partial \mu_L}{\partial \sigma}\right|_M=\left.\frac{\partial \mu_p}{\partial \sigma_p}\right|_{M}
$$
Let's write this out (suppressing the $M$):

$$
\frac{\mu_M-r_f}{\sigma_M}=\frac{\partial \mu_p}{\partial \mathbb{w}}\bigg/\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial \mathbb{w}} \Leftrightarrow \frac{\mu_M-r_f}{\sigma_M}\frac{\partial \sigma_p}{\partial \mathbb{w}}=\frac{\partial \mu_p}{\partial \mathbb{w}}
$$

From [matrix calculus](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), we know that $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}a^Tx=a$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}x^TBx=Bx+B^Tx$, and in our case, due to symmetry of $\mathbb{\Sigma}$, $\frac{\partial}{\partial w}w^T\Sigma w =2\Sigma w$. We can thus rearrange the tangency condition and find:

$$
\frac{\mu_M-r_f}{\sigma_M}\frac{1}{\sigma(w)}\mathbb{\Sigma}w=\mathbb{\mu}-\mathbb{1}r_f
$$

At $M$, the portfolio volatility and the market volatility coincide, i.e. $\sigma(w)\equiv \sigma_M$. We can hence solve for $w$ as:

$$
w=\frac{\sigma_M^2}{\mu_M-r_f}\mathbb{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\mathbb{\mu}-\mathbb{1}r_f\right)
$$

And as we are looking for a portfolio whose asset weights sum to 100%, we introduce the condition $\mathbb{1}^Tw=1$, yielding finally:

$$
\begin{align}
w_M&=\frac{w}{\mathbb{1}^Tw}\\
&=\frac{\mathbb{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\mathbb{\mu}-\mathbb{1}r_f\right)}{\mathbb{1}^T\mathbb{\Sigma}^{-1}\left(\mathbb{\mu}-\mathbb{1}r_f\right)}
\end{align}
$$

This is the formula for the *market portfolio*, derived using the tangency condition. Note that you can also arrive at this result using a Lagrangian ansatz.

HTH?

---

* NB: In practice, you will also see treasury bill rates as risk free rates as these are the most-risk-free rates available.

---

**Addendum for a problem with positivity constraints**

If your problem is bounded by non-negativity constraints, $w_i\geq 0$, one approach could be to formulate a quadratic program with a target return $m^*$:

$$
\min \frac{1}{2} w^T\Sigma w \qquad s.t. \quad w_i \geq 0,\quad w^T(\mu-r_f)=m^*
$$

You then vary $m^*$ until $\sum w_i=1$. This results in your tangency portfolio under non-negativity constraints.

Ultimatively, you could use your preferred non-linear optimizer and *simply* instruct it to maximize the Sharpe ratio s.t. non-negativity and full investment constraints....

Comment: Thank you. And if we also have the constraint that w is positive, does this calculation remain the same?

Comment: Hi Christina, it will be a bit more cumbersome as you will have to resort to quadratic programming methods. This is not really too complex, but the ansatz is a different one based on a quadratic problem with linear (in-)equality conditions.

Comment: Which of the market portfolio's inputs ($r_f, \mu, \Sigma$) contributes most to its poor out-of-sample performance?

Comment: Taking a wild guess, $\mu$ is the least stable-y estimated; but then again isn't the whole normality assumption thing a little bit wild, no?

Comment: someone said the mean-variance efficient portfolio solutions based on the sample covariance matrix do not require the assumption of normality because Markowitz never assumed it either